# React: Dynamically change style file

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

I know they've already been few questions asked related to this topic, but I tried some of given advices with no success at all.

So basically I have a React app built by create-react-app tool.
And I have multiple .css files, for each component one, but the main focus is on "darktheme.css" and "lighttheme.css".
They both look quite similar:

```
:root {
--dark-100: #161616;
--dark-150: #202020;
and so on
```

and then the components of the app (menu bar, navbar and so), just use:

```
background-color: var(--dark-150);
```

And finally to the root of all of this, my desired behaviour is that user presses button and the overall page theme is changed, dark->light/light->dark.

Currently I have it implemented in my *const handleThemeChange = (event) => {}* function, using JS, as follows:

```
if (selectedTheme === "Dark")
        import('/MYPATH/DarkTheme.css');
    else
        import('MYPATH/LightTheme.css');
```

and initially, in my *index.js* file I import darktheme.css.
When user clicks on the button for the first time, theme is really changed from (default) dark to light, but any other press doesn't work.
The issue is that after first click, both .css files are imported to page's sources and any other import of already imported stuff won't work obviously.

I'm very curious of how to solve this, because anything like:

```
const linkElement = document.getElementById('style');
if (linkElement) {
        linkElement.href = `MYPATH/${selectedThemeValue}Theme.css`;
        if (localStorage) {
            localStorage.setItem("style", `MYPATH/${selectedThemeValue}Theme.css`);
    }
}
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].disabled = true;
```

...didn't solve my problem.